# confused by hsv_to_rgb values

Tags: python

trying to make a system to allow custom gradiation of color for a turtle program im writing (simple stuff)
i've isolated the problem code

problem code:

```
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb
from math import radians

x = 0
y = 2
for j in range(y):
    print(radians(x)/10, 1, 1)
    print(hsv_to_rgb(radians(x)/10, 1, 1))
    x += 360 / y
x = 0
```

expected results:

```
0 1 1
(1, 0, 0)
0.3141592653589793 1 1
(0, 1, 1)
```

actual results:

```
0.0 1 1
(1, 0.0, 0.0)
0.3141592653589793 1 1
(0.11504440784612413, 1, 0.0)
```

to be a bit clearer on the problem, x to equal the resolution of the gradiant so for example

```
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb
from math import radians

x = 0
y = 3
for j in range(y):
    print(radians(x)/10, 1, 1)
    print(hsv_to_rgb(radians(x)/10, 1, 1))
    x += 360 / y
x = 0
```

expected result:

```
0 1 1
(1, 0, 0)
0.20943951023931953 1 1
(0, 1, 0)
0.41887902047863906 1 1
(0, 0, 1)
```

actual results:

```
0.0 1 1
(1, 0.0, 0.0)
0.20943951023931953 1 1
(0.7433629385640828, 1, 0.0)
0.41887902047863906 1 1
(0.0, 1, 0.5132741228718345)
```

Comment: Why are you passing an angle in radians to `hsv_to_rgb()`?  The documentation says it wants a value in the range 0..1.

Comment: wiki for hsv said it was in radians, ill try changing it to a decimal